# XPath - all elements inside body

Tags: php, html, xpath

I've been using this query:

```
//*[self::div or self::p or self::span]/text()[normalize-space()][string-length() > 140]
```

.. but it also fetches content from the non-required elements (`<head>` etc..) so I want to restrict the search within `<body>`, but this doesn't work for some reason:

```
//body/*[self::div or self::p or self::span]/text()[normalize-space()][string-length() > 140]
```

... for this HTML: http://pastebin.com/F4xVDL8Q

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following part of your XPath indicate that the search should be done only in *direct child* elements of `body` :

```
//body/*
```

Since you mean to search in all elements within `body` then `//*` should've been used instead :

```
//body//*[...]/text()[...][string-length() > 140]
```